# Laravel update original relation of collection model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am working with collection: `User::first()`. That model has relation `languages`. I am working with the relation, rejecting some of them, let's say:

`$languages = User::first()->languages->reject(function($language) {
   return $language->id == 1;
});`

Now, I would like to update the user's relation like:

`User::first()->languages = $languages;` where I would expect to have updated collection with filtered items. I does not work though.

Comment: You could use setRelation(). `User::first()->setRelation('languages', $languages);`

Comment: Did you mean that the languages are removed from the database (i.e those you removed from the collection?

Comment: @Bak87 Set relation did the work :)